# Casting to derived class downward

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I have a set of classes that derive one from another and the lower level has complete structure of what i need. the data stored and save is the highest level. in the highest level the Type is stored in the object. how can i cast down the highest level to the lowest. the generic see highest and T is highest which isn't helpful.

example :
Head class with couple core methods/fields :

```
[Serializable()]
public class CSelectionProperties
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> lstProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    public Dictionary<string, string> getProperties { get { return lstProperties; } }

    private Type objectType = null;
    public Type ObjectType { get { return objectType; } set { objectType = value; } }

    internal string FindProperty(string sProperty)
    {
        return FindProperty(sProperty, null);
    }

    internal string FindProperty(string sProperty, string sNullValue)
    {
        string sValue = sNullValue;
        lstProperties.TryGetValue(sProperty, out sValue);
    }
}
```

here an example of one of the many derived class :

```
[Serializable()]
public class CFilterSelectionProperties : CSelectionProperties, IFilterSelectionProperties
{
    public double getAirVolume()
    {
        return Convert.ToDouble(FindProperty("INCFMValue", "0"));
    }
}
```

Now all object using these property have the variable as `CSelectionProperties` so we can reuse everywhere same format.

When a class such as `CFilterSelectionProperties` gets created the Type get stored into the `CSelectionProperties.ObjectType`as a `Type` now another project receive a collection of `CSelectionProperties` and to properly read them i need to cast them as the proper type.

Right now i am going the old way

```
If(item is CFilterSelectionProperties)
{
     RunDataAnalysis(item as CFilterSelectionProperties);
}
Else If (item is ...)
{
     RunDataAnalysis(item as ...);
}
```

i use reflection and i stumble upon a case where i need the actual original class to loop the methods and retrieve some data. is there any way ?

Also some report will need to be open but again i have 4 class that derive from 1 single class that derive from `CSelectionProperties` at which point i don't have access to anything at all. I'm just trying to get away from If/Else which works fine.

As side note i tried going with and Activator but i can only find how to recreate a class as child type.

```
CFilterSelectionProperties oItem = new CFilterSelectionProperties(); 
MyObject.SelectionProperties = Activator.CreateInstance(oItem.ObjectType) as CSelectionProperties;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure if this is what you need but you can have a base class that "knows" the derived type:

```
class MyBase<T>  {}
class A : MyBase<A> {}
class B : MyBase<B> {}
```

this way you can do this:

```
void Foo(MyBase<T> baseObj)
{
    T derived = (T)(object)baseObj;

    // use derived in a strongly-typed manner
}
```

Comment: this is perfect. not exactly what i expected but does the job perfectly. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what `RunDataAnalysis` does it sounds like you can use virtual (or abstract) methods/properties in the base class that are overloaded in the derived classes.  Then when you call those methods/properties in `RunDataAnalysis` you will be using the most derived version without having to cast the variable.

For example:

```
public class CSelectionProperties
{
   ...  existing stuff

   public virtual DataSet GetData(.. some parameters ...)
   {
      .. do stuff common to ALL subtypes
   }
}
```

and

```
public class CFilterSelectionProperties : CSelectionProperties, IFilterSelectionProperties
{
    public override DAtaSet GetData(... some parameters ...)
    {
       ... do stuff common to THIS type and subtypes
    }
}
```

Comment: that's what i was going for originally until i got the message that this work had to be in a separate project so it can run on a simulation server. But yes if that wasn't the case i don't see anything better.